# libstd-rs error in yocto project with openstlinux distribution

Tags: stm32, yocto

I am working yocto project. I started with a custom board based on stm32mp157. You can find the board description in this link  [custom board](https://www.emtrion.de/de/products/emsbc-argon-single-board-computer.html). Vendor has a board support package in dunfell version. But I am doing my project in kirkstone version. I have choosen my distribution packgae from the openstlinuxdistribution. I have following build configuration for creating the image:

```
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "2.0.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-emt_eglfs-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "emsbc-argon"
DISTRO               = "emt-eglfs"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "1.3"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm vfp cortexa7 neon vfpv4 thumb callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
DISTRO_CODENAME      = "kirkstone"
ACCEPT_EULA_emsbc-argon = "1"
GCCVERSION           = "11.%"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel = "linux-stm32mp-argon"
meta-emtrion-emsbc-argon 
meta-emtrion         = "<unknown>:<unknown>"
meta                 = "HEAD:f7766da462905ec67bf549d46b8017be36cd5b2a"
meta-oe                   
meta-initramfs       
meta-multimedia      
meta-python          
meta-networking      
meta-webserver       
meta-filesystems      
meta-perl            = "HEAD:05dcac98473402d87e0af73bbc2c5a6a840abe93"
meta-qt5             = "HEAD:5b71df60e523423b9df6793de9387f87a149ac42"
meta-st-stm32mp      = "HEAD:ca501bd7dbe023682903ceedddaacd940b0898f4"
meta-st-openstlinux  = "HEAD:cb736b403d0fef2a02390695613b6b4bb13ca1b7"
meta-gnome           
meta-xfce            = "HEAD:05dcac98473402d87e0af73bbc2c5a6a840abe93"
```

I have created two custom layer, which added in the bblayers.conf file. I do not have anything named as libstd-rs in my recipe. I tried bitbake -c cleanall and cleansstate, but still have the error. I have the following error:

Summary: 1 task failed:
ERROR: Task (/home/hico/work/emtrion/argon-yocto/test-st-yocto/layers/openembedded-
core/meta/recipes-devtools/rust/libstd-rs_1.59.0.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'

You can find the log file in this link [logfile](https://pastebin.com/je4grA8P). Does anyone have any idea to solve this error? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you try setting `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable in the recipe, and try to compile once again? It won't solve any problems, but hopefully will give an exact stacktrace when it dies, showing why/where it segfaults

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestions. Here is the [logfile](https://pastebin.com/YNYvgDzG)    after setting RUST_BACKTRACE=1 .

Comment: Huhh, I was really hoping that it will give some reasonable clues... I was obviously wrong.

Comment: Hmmm, why does it say `rustc = ` in the 3rd line? And despite this, I wonder why some of the commands succeed... What values did you set for `BUILD_SYS`, `HOST_SYS` and `TARGET_SYS` variables when you copiled rust?

Comment: I looked into my recipes, I do not set anzything as **BUILD_SYS**, **HOST_SYS**, **TARGET_SYS**. The rust recipe is from the openmebedded-core/meta layer. I do not have any custom rust recipe. This is why I am wondering, that I do not have any rust dependency.

Comment: Finally I solved the error. It was very unlikely. The rust library was needed for TUNE_FEATURES and in recent openembedded-core layer they changed their recipe. they deleted one line from rust-common.inc file. For this reason it was giving an Error. In logfile it did not had any error, I followed the warning msg **Signal 11:SIGSEV**, and found the solution in this [link](https://github.com/meta-rust/meta-rust/issues/240). Now I compiled the whole image without any error and I also booted that image in the custom board. Thanks again for your help.